# Assistance writing a recursive function that sums a list of arrays in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm attempting to write a recursive program that adds up the sum of a list of arrays. It requires use of a helper function, as reflected below.

I am failing to see what I am doing wrong, but I think it has to do with a failure to get the program to remove items from the list after they are added up. Could anyone help me?

EDIT:
Let me explain my logic in pseudocode:
I want to get the program to recognize an item in an array list and store that in double sum. Then through recursive passing I want to keep repeating this process by moving through the items in the list of arrays and add them to double sum.

```
public static double sum (double[] a) {
    double sum = 0;
    return sumHelper (a, a.length-1, sum); // TODO
}

public static double sumHelper (double[] a, int i, double sum) 
{
    if (a.length == 0) {
        return sumHelper (a, a-1, sum);
    }
    else {
        sum = sum + a[i];
        i = i-1;
        a.length -1; // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
        return sumHelper (a, a-1, sum);
    }   
    return sum;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    double[] list0 = new double[] {};
    double[] list1 = new double[] { 5 };
    double[] list2 = new double[] { -3, 5 };
    double[] list3 = new double[] { 2, -3, 5 };
    double[] list4 = new double[] { -1, 2, -3, 5 };
    double[] list5 = new double[] { 33, 44, 55 };

    System.out.println("Display the sum of the array contents");
    System.out.println ("list5: " +sum (list5));
    System.out.println ("list0: " +sum (list0));
    System.out.println ("list1: " +sum (list1));
    System.out.println ("list2: " +sum (list2));
    System.out.println ("list3: " +sum (list3));
    System.out.println ("list4: " +sum (list4));
```

Comment: where is the recursion?

Comment: You never call sumHelper in the else block of sumHelper so there isn't any recursion happening

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the recursive lines, which I temporarily removed to test shortening the length of the arrays by other means. It is edited to include them again.

Comment: Also you are passing the index to the helper so you don't need to modify the array at all, just update the index and sum

Comment: `a.length -1; // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK` Of course it doesn't. This syntax is invalid.

Comment: `int sum = Arrays.asList(list0).stream().reduce(0,(a,b)->a+b);`

Comment: Here `sumHelper (a, a-1, sum);` you subtract `1` from array. What result do you expect to get?

Comment: @talex that was my attempt to remove a[i], but that may be faulty logic.

Answer (score 1):

Is this is what you are trying to do?

```
public static double sum (double[] a) {
    double sum = 0;
    return sumHelper (a, a.length-1, sum); // TODO
}

public static double sumHelper (double[] a, int i, double sum) 
{
    if (i < 0) { 
        return sum;
    }
    else {
        sum = sum + a[i];
        i = i-1;
        return sumHelper (a, i, sum);
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] list0 = new double[] {};
    double[] list1 = new double[] { 5 };
    double[] list2 = new double[] { -3, 5 };
    double[] list3 = new double[] { 2, -3, 5 };
    double[] list4 = new double[] { -1, 2, -3, 5 };
    double[] list5 = new double[] { 33, 44, 55 };

    System.out.println("Display the sum of the array contents");
    System.out.println ("list5: " +sum (list5));
    System.out.println ("list0: " +sum (list0));
    System.out.println ("list1: " +sum (list1));
    System.out.println ("list2: " +sum (list2));
    System.out.println ("list3: " +sum (list3));
    System.out.println ("list4: " +sum (list4));

}
```

Results:

> Display the sum of the array contents
>   list5: 132.0
>   list0: 0.0
>   list1: 5.0
>   list2: 2.0
>   list3: 4.0
>   list4: 3.0

Comment: That was pretty much it. Clearly I confused my death to death by trying to adjust i both recursively and within main, and then on top of that needlessly trying to adjust the length of a in three different places. This is tremendously helpful! Sorry for the newcomer question!

Comment: Anyways Java arrays length are immutable. (You can't change the length).

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the variables, a-1 instead of i.
And array will start from 0 index, So you need to add the elements till the 0 index.

```
static double[] list0 = new double[] {};
        static double[] list1 = new double[] { 5 };
        static double[] list2 = new double[] { -3, 5 };
        static double[] list3 = new double[] { 2, -3, 5 };
        static double[] list4 = new double[] { -1, 2, -3, 5 };
        static double[] list5 = new double[] { 33, 44, 55 };
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TOsuDO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Display the sum of the array contents");
            System.out.println ("list5: " +sum (list5));
            System.out.println ("list0: " +sum (list0));
            System.out.println ("list1: " +sum (list1));
            System.out.println ("list2: " +sum (list2));
            System.out.println ("list3: " +sum (list3));
            System.out.println ("list4: " +sum (list4));
        }
        public static double sum (double[] a) {
            double sum = 0;
            return sumHelper (a, a.length-1, sum); // TODO
        }
        public static double sumHelper (double[] a, int i, double sum) 
        {
            if (i == -1) {
                {
                    System.out.println("Added all the elements");
                    return sum;
                }
            }
            else {
                sum = sum + a[i];
                i = i-1;
                //a.length -1; // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
                return sumHelper (a, i, sum);
            }
        }
```